# Get slope between two cells in gdistance

Tags: r, r-raster

I have created the following Transition Object from a raster containing altitude values of a landscape in R:

```
wd <- "C:/Users/LG/Dropbox/Random Walk"                                         
setwd(wd)                                                                       

    library(gdistance)
    library(raster)


    r <- raster("altitude.tif")
    altDiff <- function(x){x[2] - x[1]}
    hd <- transition(r, altDiff, 8, symm=FALSE)

    slope <- geoCorrection(hd)
```

As you can see the function I use to create said objecs is the difference in altitude between two cells, which is then corrected into the slope between cells via the 'geocorrection' function. How can I access the slope between two cells of my choice now ? In order to complete my script I need to get the slope values  between a cell of my choice and all eight cells that are adjacent to it. So basically I want to know how I can access the transition values for two cells of my choice?
If anybody could help me with this I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the vignette of the gdistance package, which explains this fully.

To get the slope between cells 1 and 2, you can do:

```
slope[1,2]
```

Take a look at the `adjacent` function in the raster package to get a full list of the 8 adjacent cells.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have read the vignette, but that was a while ago and now that I started programming I just skimmed through it and didn't find anything helpful. In addition I didn't remember reading anything regarding my problem so i decided to quickly post my question here.

Comment: Anyway thanks for helping me out with this, it is much appreciated !